# Report Generated but email not sent

Tags: reporting

I have scheduled a report at 5:00 AM everyday.

Looking at the "Background Jobs" I can see that my report has been generated but I did not get any email from Salesforce.

While customizing the report I did mention the list of users to whom this report should be sent and yet the report has not been sent as email.

Can someone tell me how to start the debugging or throw some ideas as to what would have gone wrong ?[image]

[image]

Comment: One clarifying question: do you receive any other emails from Salesforce? Or is this the only email that isn't successful?

Comment: This is the only email (report) which I did not get

Comment: Random idea, though I acknowledge it's a long shot: have you tested email deliverability from Salesforce? It's possible that this email happens to be coming from a Salesforce IP that is having deliverability issues to your mail server. This actually happened to me once. There was a bank of Salesforce IPs that couldn't find our mail server for some reason, so any emails originating from those IPs would fail.